# Share Exchange Server hosted calendar with GMail user from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, exchange, calendar

Using Outlook 2019 Professional Plus (or associated OWA), connected to Exchange Server 2016 inside an organization's Active Directory domain, **can you share a calendar with a *specific* GMail user**?

I've tried right clicking a user's calendar, going to permissions, and add someone outside the organization (a contact with GMail address). But that "Add Users" dialog won't allow you to select a contact outside the domain at all.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of set up at all with Exchange Server?

Can I configure Exchange in a way where users can share their calendar from Outlook (either the Windows 10 client, or from OWA) to a GMail user, in a way that it stays reasonably synched (so the GMail user sees updates no less than 1 hour after they were done in Outlook)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill Suppose I further clarify that the question is whether/how it's possible _in general_ (i.e. remove bits about "...your network"), would you estimate this question has any chance on serverfault instead? I've checked their "On-Topic" page and Exchange Server seems to be within scope?

Comment: That is, I was trying (but perhaps failed) to keep out "_my_ IT department". I want to know if it's possible at all to achieve my goal given this software.